# T-SQL Algorithm to Encode Unsafe HTML Characters as HTML Character Entity References

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, html-entities

I need to create an **after insert trigger** in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The trigger needs to take some fields from INSERTED, process them and put them in different fields in the same row which was inserted.

Re. processing:

I need help coming up with an **algorithm** in T-SQL code, which **encodes unsafe HTML characters** such as < (less than) and > (greater than) as **HTML character references**.

Ideally, I would like to do this in a manner similar to ASP.NET Server.HtmlEncode(myUnsafeHtml), and ideally without using literals all over the place or extra tables i.e. a clever algorithm.

**Just asking for help.**

So in summary, the after insert trigger takes the value in **UnsafeHtml column**, processes it and puts it in **SafeHtml column** in the row which was inserted.

Both columns are of type **NVARCHAR**.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Having thought about it a **UDF** would be more appropriate which I could use in many places.

Comment: Why would one want to do this on the database level?

Comment: That's an obvious question, and the reason I can't / won't do it in the application is because it's a black box which I cannot easily modify without investing a lot of time learning. I like quick and dirty (but robust) solutions that get the job done!

Comment: Can you show an example of the column in a before and after state?

Comment: @Blam I always like to try something new and I tried CLR and never again.

Comment: What did you not like about CLR?

Comment: @Blam I'm sure it has useful purposes e.g. string processing, regex pattern matching etc. but due to the restrictions on what you can do with CLR you may as well create a small console app to do whatever you can't do in T-SQL and set it up as a task in a SQL Server job or something along those lines.

Comment: You don't need to reply but the stated problem is string processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Encoding five special characters with recursive CTE:**

```
DECLARE 
  @unsafe NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @safe   NVARCHAR(MAX) 

--
-- Create the unsafe html string
-- 
SET @unsafe = N'html''s encoding "method" is <= or >= & 1234 ' + NCHAR(129) 
--
-- Use a recursive CTE to iterate through each character in the string
-- 
;WITH cte AS 
(
  -- 
  -- The first row will contain the original
  -- string, an empty string to be used to 
  -- build the "safe" string, and a position
  -- column to mark the character position
  -- of the loop
  -- 
  SELECT 
    @unsafe AS unsafe_html,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), '') AS safe_html,
    1 AS pos
  WHERE @unsafe IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@unsafe) > 0 
  UNION ALL
  -- 
  -- Create a loop: 
  -- The anchor row starts at position one.
  -- Increment the position by one for each pass.
  -- Stop when the position value is equal to the string lenth.
  -- Evaluate the character in each string
  -- If the ASCII value > 128, use the &# format.
  -- Otherwise, check for 5 special characters: " & ' < >
  -- Use the encoding reference or just the original character
  --
  SELECT 
    @unsafe AS unsafe_html,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), safe_html + 
    CASE WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTRING(unsafe_html, pos, 1)) > 128 
         THEN '&#' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), UNICODE(SUBSTRING(unsafe_html, pos, 1)))  
         ELSE CASE SUBSTRING(unsafe_html, pos, 1)
              WHEN '"'  THEN '&quot' 
              WHEN '&'  THEN '&amp'
              WHEN '''' THEN '&apos'
              WHEN '<'  THEN '&lt'
              WHEN '>'  THEN '&gt'
              ELSE SUBSTRING(unsafe_html, pos, 1)
              END 
         END ) AS safe_html,
    pos + 1 AS pos
  FROM cte
  WHERE pos <= LEN(@unsafe)
) 
--
-- Each pass through the string creates a row in the CTE
-- The last row will have the position value of the string length + 1
-- Use that row as the safe html string
-- SQL Server allows a max recursion of 32767
-- 
SELECT @safe = (
  SELECT safe_html 
  FROM cte
  WHERE pos = LEN(@unsafe) + 1
) 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767) 

SELECT @safe

-- html&aposs encoding &quotmethod&quot is &lt= or &gt= &amp 1234 &#129
```

**Initial version:**

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100)

SET @s = '<html>unsafe & safe<html>'
SELECT @s 
SELECT (SELECT @s FOR XML PATH(''))

---------------------------------------
<html>unsafe & safe<html>

-----------------------------------------
&lt;html&gt;unsafe &amp; safe&lt;html&gt;
```

**Full encoding with all official references:**

```
DECLARE 
    @unsafe  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @safe NVARCHAR(MAX) 

-- Build string with first 10,000 unicode chars
SELECT @unsafe = COALESCE(@unsafe, '') + NCHAR(number) + ' ' 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS number
    FROM sys.all_objects s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects s2 
) t

-- Build table variable with character entity references defined in HTML 4.0
-- Reference: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/characterentities_famsupp_69.html
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    unicode_val INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
) 

INSERT @t 
VALUES
('&quot', 34),
('&amp', 38),
('&apos', 39),
('&lt', 60),
('&gt', 62),
('&nbsp', 160),
('&iexcl', 161),
('&cent', 162),
('&pound', 163),
('&curren', 164),
('&yen', 165),
('&brvbar', 166),
('&sect', 167),
('&uml', 168),
('&copy', 169),
('&ordf', 170),
('&laquo', 171),
('&not', 172),
('&shy', 173),
('&reg', 174),
('&macr', 175),
('&deg', 176),
('&plusmn', 177),
('&sup2', 178),
('&sup3', 179),
('&acute', 180),
('&micro', 181),
('&para', 182),
('&middot', 183),
('&cedil', 184),
('&sup1', 185),
('&ordm', 186),
('&raquo', 187),
('&frac14', 188),
('&frac12', 189),
('&frac34', 190),
('&iquest', 191),
('&Agrave', 192),
('&Aacute', 193),
('&Acirc', 194),
('&Atilde', 195),
('&Auml', 196),
('&Aring', 197),
('&AElig', 198),
('&Ccedil', 199),
('&Egrave', 200),
('&Eacute', 201),
('&Ecirc', 202),
('&Euml', 203),
('&Igrave', 204),
('&Iacute', 205),
('&Icirc', 206),
('&Iuml', 207),
('&ETH', 208),
('&Ntilde', 209),
('&Ograve', 210),
('&Oacute', 211),
('&Ocirc', 212),
('&Otilde', 213),
('&Ouml', 214),
('&times', 215),
('&Oslash', 216),
('&Ugrave', 217),
('&Uacute', 218),
('&Ucirc', 219),
('&Uuml', 220),
('&Yacute', 221),
('&THORN', 222),
('&szlig', 223),
('&agrave', 224),
('&aacute', 225),
('&acirc', 226),
('&atilde', 227),
('&auml', 228),
('&aring', 229),
('&aelig', 230),
('&ccedil', 231),
('&egrave', 232),
('&eacute', 233),
('&ecirc', 234),
('&euml', 235),
('&igrave', 236),
('&iacute', 237),
('&icirc', 238),
('&iuml', 239),
('&eth', 240),
('&ntilde', 241),
('&ograve', 242),
('&oacute', 243),
('&ocirc', 244),
('&otilde', 245),
('&ouml', 246),
('&divide', 247),
('&oslash', 248),
('&ugrave', 249),
('&uacute', 250),
('&ucirc', 251),
('&uuml', 252),
('&yacute', 253),
('&thorn', 254),
('&yuml', 255),
('&OElig', 338),
('&oelig', 339),
('&Scaron', 352),
('&scaron', 353),
('&Yuml', 376),
('&fnof', 402),
('&circ', 710),
('&tilde', 732),
('&Alpha', 913),
('&Beta', 914),
('&Gamma', 915),
('&Delta', 916),
('&Epsilon', 917),
('&Zeta', 918),
('&Eta', 919),
('&Theta', 920),
('&Iota', 921),
('&Kappa', 922),
('&Lambda', 923),
('&Mu', 924),
('&Nu', 925),
('&Xi', 926),
('&Omicron', 927),
('&Pi', 928),
('&Rho', 929),
('&Sigma', 931),
('&Tau', 932),
('&Upsilon', 933),
('&Phi', 934),
('&Chi', 935),
('&Psi', 936),
('&Omega', 937),
('&alpha', 945),
('&beta', 946),
('&gamma', 947),
('&delta', 948),
('&epsilon', 949),
('&zeta', 950),
('&eta', 951),
('&theta', 952),
('&iota', 953),
('&kappa', 954),
('&lambda', 955),
('&mu', 956),
('&nu', 957),
('&xi', 958),
('&omicron', 959),
('&pi', 960),
('&rho', 961),
('&sigmaf', 962),
('&sigma', 963),
('&tau', 964),
('&upsilon', 965),
('&phi', 966),
('&chi', 967),
('&psi', 968),
('&omega', 969),
('&thetasym', 977),
('&upsih', 978),
('&piv', 982),
('&ensp', 8194),
('&emsp', 8195),
('&thinsp', 8201),
('&zwnj', 8204),
('&zwj', 8205),
('&lrm', 8206),
('&rlm', 8207),
('&ndash', 8211),
('&mdash', 8212),
('&lsquo', 8216),
('&rsquo', 8217),
('&sbquo', 8218),
('&ldquo', 8220),
('&rdquo', 8221),
('&bdquo', 8222),
('&dagger', 8224),
('&Dagger', 8225),
('&bull', 8226),
('&hellip', 8230),
('&permil', 8240),
('&prime', 8242),
('&Prime', 8243),
('&lsaquo', 8249),
('&rsaquo', 8250),
('&oline', 8254),
('&frasl', 8260),
('&euro', 8364),
('&image', 8465),
('&weierp', 8472),
('&real', 8476),
('&trade', 8482),
('&alefsym', 8501),
('&larr', 8592),
('&uarr', 8593),
('&rarr', 8594),
('&darr', 8595),
('&harr', 8596),
('&crarr', 8629),
('&lArr', 8656),
('&uArr', 8657),
('&rArr', 8658),
('&dArr', 8659),
('&hArr', 8660),
('&forall', 8704),
('&part', 8706),
('&exist', 8707),
('&empty', 8709),
('&nabla', 8711),
('&isin', 8712),
('&notin', 8713),
('&ni', 8715),
('&prod', 8719),
('&sum', 8721),
('&minus', 8722),
('&lowast', 8727),
('&radic', 8730),
('&prop', 8733),
('&infin', 8734),
('&ang', 8736),
('&and', 8743),
('&or', 8744),
('&cap', 8745),
('&cup', 8746),
('&int', 8747),
('&there4', 8756),
('&sim', 8764),
('&cong', 8773),
('&asymp', 8776),
('&ne', 8800),
('&equiv', 8801),
('&le', 8804),
('&ge', 8805),
('&sub', 8834),
('&sup', 8835),
('&nsub', 8836),
('&sube', 8838),
('&supe', 8839),
('&oplus', 8853),
('&otimes', 8855),
('&perp', 8869),
('&sdot', 8901),
('&lceil', 8968),
('&rceil', 8969),
('&lfloor', 8970),
('&rfloor', 8971),
('&lang', 9001),
('&rang', 9002),
('&loz', 9674),
('&spades', 9824),
('&clubs', 9827),
('&hearts', 9829),
('&diams', 9830)

-- Build numbers table to parse the string
DECLARE @numbers TABLE (number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) 
INSERT @numbers
SELECT TOP (LEN(@unsafe)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS number
FROM sys.all_objects s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects s2

-- Use numbers table to parse each character.
-- If a match is found in character entity reference table,
-- then use the safe substitute. Otherwise, if the unicode
-- value is greater than 128, use &#<unicode char value>.
-- Finally, use the original character if nothing else
-- is a match
SELECT @safe = COALESCE(@safe,'') 
       + COALESCE(name, 
         CASE WHEN UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@unsafe, number, 1)) > 128 THEN '&#' 
          + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@unsafe, number, 1))) 
          ELSE SUBSTRING(@unsafe, number, 1) END)
FROM @numbers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t  
  ON UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@unsafe, number, 1)) = unicode_val

SELECT @safe AS [safe]

Results:  
! &quot # $ % &amp &apos ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; 
&lt = &gt ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
[ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { 
| } ~   &#129 &#130 &#131 &#132 &#133 &#134 &#135 &#136 &#137 &#138 
&#139 &#140 &#141 &#142 &#143 &#144 &#145 &#146 &#147 &#148 &#149 
&#150 &#151 &#152 &#153 &#154 &#155 &#156 &#157 &#158 &#159 &nbsp 
&iexcl &cent &pound &curren &yen &brvbar &sect &uml &copy &ordf 
&laquo &not &shy &reg &macr &deg &plusmn &sup2 &sup3 &acute &micro 
&para &middot &cedil &sup1 &ordm &raquo &frac14 &frac12 &frac34 
&iquest &Agrave &Aacute &Acirc &Atilde &Auml &Aring &AElig &Ccedil 
&Egrave &Eacute &Ecirc &Euml &Igrave &Iacute &Icirc &Iuml &ETH &Ntilde 
&Ograve &Oacute &Ocirc &Otilde &Ouml &times &Oslash &Ugrave &Uacute 
&Ucirc &Uuml &Yacute &THORN &szlig &agrave &aacute &acirc &atilde &auml 
&aring &aelig &ccedil &egrave &eacute &ecirc &euml &igrave &iacute &icirc 
&iuml &eth &ntilde &ograve &oacute &ocirc &otilde &ouml &divide &oslash 
&ugrave &uacute &ucirc &uuml &yacute &thorn &yuml &#256 &#257 &#258 &#259 
&#260 &#261 &#262 &#263 &#264 &#265 &#266...
```

Comment: It might be I'll have to do some testing, but yes this looks better than what I had in mind.

Comment: @ChrisCannon: added 2nd version which includes all entity character references from HTML4 and converts any unicode chars > 128 to &#<unicode char value)

Comment: I'm sure this works but it is a bit complicated to go into a UDF e.g. doing CROSS JOINs with sys.all_objects I don't understand and it feels wrong. Surely a lot of this code would be better off as a table somewhere - I know I didn't want that but it would be preferable to putting all the above code in a UDF. I think I am leaning more towards a solution where common characters like ampersand, less than, greater than, and quotes are encoded as named entity references, and everything else apart from A-Z and 0-9 plus space, period, comma etc. is encoded using decimal entity references.

Comment: @ChrisCannon: I agree. The list of unicode values and their encoded values belong in a maintained table. And the CROSS JOIN is just an easy way to create a Numbers table. The Numbers table is in order to do a fast evaluation of each character in the string. But having both of these in a Reference database would be reasonable.

Comment: Posted version 3. Uses recursion to avoid numbers table but limited to string length of ~32K. Encodes five special characters and anything above ASCII 128.

Comment: Wow I'm impressed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @Expression nvarchar(max) = 'Y<1'

Select @Expression = (Select @Expression For XML Path(''))

Select @Expression
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a SQL UDF in .NET that calls Server.HtmlEncode(myUnsafeHtml) and loading that into the SQL server? To get started:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37377/SQL-Server-CLR-Functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Been there done that doesn't work because you have to register the system.web and system.drawing dlls and it's a nightmare and very risky for a production server. It doesn't work because SQL Server complains that the assemblies are "untested and unsafe". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Riskier than a home-grown T-SQL encoding algorithm?