# Get HTML Codes from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single quote in a column name, and I want to translate it to `&#39;`, is there any function to translate a character into a html code?
Thank you.

Comment: there is no a function in sql server to do this? :(

Comment: Why do it in SQL? Wouldn't your development framework be a better place?

Comment: is crazy I know, but I would like to retrieve it already from sql and push it into the client

Comment: @rgx71 No, there is no native function in SQL server to do this. You will have to write your own user defined function. Here are some native string manipulation methods which may be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858646/t-sql-algorithm-to-encode-unsafe-html-characters-as-html-character-entity-refere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), but you'll have to replace every entity manually.

```
SELECT REPLACE(YourColumn, '''', '&#39;') FROM YourTable
```

But as I said in the comments, SQL isn't really the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ASCII ( character_expression )

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx