# Convert Plain Text to HTML

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having HTML code text as

`select prd_desc from prd_mst`

```
prd_desc
------------------------------------------------
&lt;u&gt;hello&lt;/u&gt; &lt;font color=&quot;#cc0000&quot;&gt;dfgfdg&lt;/font&gt;
```

How can i make it format in a HTML as 'hello...'

I am using replace function for all those special HTML characters or sqlserver has some shortcut, function for it.

Comment: just need to pick 'hello' from all these special characters

Comment: no.. i want to pick all text

Comment: I am reading to another post similar `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858646/t-sql-algorithm-to-encode-unsafe-html-characters-as-html-character-entity-refere`

Comment: Some interesting suggestions here: http://sqlsunday.com/2013/04/07/url-encoding-function/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905193/tsql-how-to-url-encode

Comment: What do you want to do with `font` and `color` from your sample string? Those are "text" just like "hello" is text. How will you know when a substring is text and when it's HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
create  FUNCTION udf_HtmlDecode  
(  
    @UnDecoded as varchar(max)  
)  
RETURNS varchar(500)  
AS  
BEGIN  
--declare @UnDecoded as varchar(500);  
--set @UnDecoded = 'xvfxv &lt;u&gt;cbgdfgd&lt;/u&gt; &lt;font color=&quot;#cc0000&quot;&gt;dfgfdg&lt;/font&gt; &lt;b&gt;gdfgdf&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;';  
  DECLARE @Encoded as varchar(max)  

  --order is important here. Replace the amp first, then the lt and gt.   
  --otherwise the &lt will become &amp;lt;   
  SELECT @Encoded = Replace(  
  Replace(  
    Replace(  
      Replace(@UnDecoded,'&amp;','&'),  
    '&lt;', '<'),  
  '&gt;', '>'),  
'&quot;','"')    
 RETURN @Encoded  
--select @Encoded  
END
```

then execute

`select dbo.udf_HtmlDecode('&lt;u&gt;hello&lt;/u&gt; &lt;font color=&quot;#cc0000&quot;&gt;dfgfdg&lt;/font&gt;')`

will return

`<u>hello</u> <font color="#cc0000">dfgfdg</font>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the XML datatype for this.

If you cast your value to XML that will give you a XML fragment that consists of one text element only. Extract that value using the `value()` function and you have a string that is not entitized.

```sql
select cast(p.prd_desc as xml).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as prd_desc
from dbo.prd_mst as p
```

Result:

```
prd_desc
-------------------------------------------------
<u>hello</u> <font color="#cc0000">dfgfdg</font>
```